# How can I parse/extract from a string in PHP? Specifically something between quotes

Tags: php, json, string

I have a string like this

```
{"2":{"name":"Moon Center","value":"moon7","value_raw":"moon7","id":2,"type":"select"},"3":{"name":"Multiple Choice","value":"Second Choice","value_raw":"Second Choice","id":3,"type":"radio"}}
```

How do I get for example, the content inside value to a variable? And I would want to be able to get it for every item with value in there. There will be several that come from a form in a single string.

This is the response from a form that stores the whole string in a string. Kinda wish it was an array but this is what i'm working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string is actually a JSON value. To get the data out of it, you must first [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) it to an array (or object). If you choose an array, you can then use [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to get all the `'value'` values:

```
$json = '{"2":{"name":"Moon Center","value":"moon7","value_raw":"moon7","id":2,"type":"select"},"3":{"name":"Multiple Choice","value":"Second Choice","value_raw":"Second Choice","id":3,"type":"radio"}}';
$array = json_decode($json, true);
print_r(array_column($array, 'value'));
```

Output:

```
Array (
  [0] => moon7
  [1] => Second Choice 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/nN6t8)

Comment: Wait what. The string i'm getting is from a SQL Query single field. SQL fields can contain JSON?

Comment: To clarify. It's an array that has a single item, and that array[0]->field contains the string you are seeing. Are you sure I have to treat it like JSON?

Comment: @Sigma absolutely. Many DBMS directly support JSON fields these days (e.g. [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html)) but regardless of that you could always store JSON into a text column.

Comment: @Sigma well, it is JSON, so it's certainly much easier to process it that way.

Comment: So i tried this
$string = $logResults[0]->fields; //$string becomes the JSON you see in the question
$array = json_decode($string, true);
echo $array[0]->value;

But it's not displaying anythiing. Your example also crashes because array_column only takes one param or so it says.

Comment: @Sigma `array_column` definitely takes two parameters, and you can see the demo working with the exact string from your question on the link I provided.

Comment: Okay it was definitely a typo on my end. But why doesn't this work for single access echo $array[0]->value;  Is that not how I should get my values in an array usually?

Comment: @Sigma If you `print_r($array);` after the `json_decode`, you'll see the indexes are `2` and `3` (derived from the JSON). If you want it to start at 0, use `$array = array_values(json_decode($json, true));`. Note that you need to use `$array[2]['value']` as `json_decode($json, true)` will convert all levels of the JSON into arrays, not objects.

Comment: Ugh you're right it was pushing it starting on 2. I just went with the logical "first". Sorry for the amateur questions. Frustration has gotten the best of me today and clouded my thinking. Thanks!